# how do i generate SQL script at runtime in VB6.0

Tags: vb6

how do i Generate SQL Script at runtime from VB6.0 and DB as SQL Server, generate all tables,views,PK,FK.Stored Procedures,Triggers from existing database. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to do this sort of thing was to use the SQL Distributed Object Model that you get with SQL Server and it works great with VB6.  The last time I tried it was with SQL Server 2000 but the theory should still be good.

Give this link a try as a good start and take it from there, this shows you how to get at the stored procedures http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315505

Once you have got this bit down the other bits you need should be simple enough.

I hope this helps.

Cheers

Comment: "SQL Server Database Management Objects (SQL-DMO) has been removed from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and the SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack. SQL-DMO also does not support Database Engine features introduced after SQL Server 2000.... Do not use SQL-DMO in new development work; use SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) instead. You can obtain the SMO documentation by installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).